# Node & SQL: Check if a value is in the column

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I am using Node.js (discord.js specifically) to make a Discord bot. I have a command called `!add` which takes 2+ arguments. `!add Name This is the reply` (`Name` would be `args[0]`). This is my code I use to check if the `Name` they input has already been created by a user:

```
var info = {
 "commandname": args[0],
 "commandreply": args.join(" ").slice(1),
 "username": message.author.name,
 "userid": message.author.id
 }

connection.query("SELECT * FROM commands WHERE commandname = " + args[0], info, function(error) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // should only fireif that command name already exists as a command.
  return message.channel.sendMessage("A command with command name " + args[0] + " already exists."); 
});

// SHOULD fire - as no commands in my database yet. Especially not with that name.
console.log("Trying to insert command " + args[0] + " into Database.");
```

But I am getting an error when I run this command:

```
Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'Name' in 'where clause'
```

This is my full code for the `add` command if you want to take a look:https://hastebin.com/qulivabeko.js

This is how my database currently looks: [http://imgur.com/a/L7fYI](https://imgur.com/a/L7fYI)

I am *really* new to SQL.

Comment: args[0] should be quoted and you really should work out how to add parameters so that sql injection issues are resolved.

Answer (score -1):

First of all your code is prone to sql injection. First escape all inputs made by the users and then fix your query mistake. It should be like this:  `SELECT * FROM commands WHERE commandname = '" + args[0] + "'"`

Comment: With that, I got `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. Link to picture: http://imgur.com/a/RtZ2v

Comment: No I shouldn't need that there beause it's a function and I have `});` when I close it. Anyway I added it and got the same response.

Comment: ouch my mistake... Let me take a look on the original error. Undo that change

Comment: I edited the query... I clearly wrote that too fast and made a mistake with the quotes. Sorry. Also you don't need that " on the end. The query should start with "SELECT and end with " ' "

Comment: Okay so that didn't cause that error now, which is good. But when I ran the command `!add Test hello`, in my console it gave me `Trying to insert Command Test into Database` (which it should! :)) However, it also gave me the response `A command with command name Test already exists` (Which is does not).

Comment: why shouldn't you see the second message? You are clearly sending it after the query is done just below the if (err) throw err so this must be expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142662/discussion-between-slowdeath007-and-rusty).

Comment: Your example is still vulnerable to SQL injection.